# How do I format a column based on grouped values?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame that looks like the top table of the attached image.

I have groups of names where a name can belong to one of the following categories: `category 1`, `category 2`, and `special`.

I want to output a data frame where only one category is present for each name based on the highest number in the number column.

If an special category is present, then that name should be a `special` category regardless of the number value.

Please refer to the bottom table of the attached image as an example of the output I am looking for.

my_data:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Name A", "Name A", "Name B", "Name B", 
"Name C", "Name C", "Name C"), Category = c("Category 1", "Category 2", 
"Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Special"
), Number = c(10L, 5L, 3L, 20L, 3L, 25L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

[image]

Comment: You need to present your data in text format and not as images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another tidyverse method that maintains the row ordering:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Name)%>%
  mutate(Category = ifelse("Special"%in%Category ,'Special', 
                           Category[which.max(Number)]))
# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name   Category   Number
  <chr>  <chr>       <int>
1 Name A Category 1     10
2 Name A Category 1      5
3 Name B Category 2      3
4 Name B Category 2     20
5 Name C Special         3
6 Name C Special        25
7 Name C Special         4
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do it this way:

By arranging in descending form (`-`) we maintain the row order to use `first()` function in mutate:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  arrange(-Number, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Category = ifelse("Special" %in% Category, "Special", first(Category)))
```

```
 Name   Category   Number
  <chr>  <chr>       <int>
1 Name A Category 1     10
2 Name A Category 1      5
3 Name B Category 2     20
4 Name B Category 2      3
5 Name C Special        25
6 Name C Special         4
7 Name C Special         3
```

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Name A", "Name A", "Name B", "Name B", 
"Name C", "Name C", "Name C"), Category = c("Category 1", "Category 2", 
"Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Special"
), Number = c(10L, 5L, 3L, 20L, 3L, 25L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```